# Tree diagram in same line

Tags: tex-core

I'm trying to put the tree diagrams in the same line but they are coming in different lines.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\let\cleardoublepage=\clearpage
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
treenode/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
    draw, align=center,
    top color=white, bottom color=blue!20},
root/.style     = {treenode, font=\Large, bottom color=red!30},
env/.style      = {treenode, font=\ttfamily\normalsize},
dummy/.style    = {circle,draw}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[
grow                    = right,
sibling distance        = 6em,
level distance          = 8em,
edge from parent/.style = {draw, -latex},
every node/.style       = {font=\footnotesize},
sloped
]
\node [root] {$L_1$}
child { node [env] {z}
    edge from parent node [below] {1-p} }
child { node [env] {x}
    edge from parent node [above] {p} };

\end{tikzpicture}

$\sim$

\begin{tikzpicture}
[
grow                    = right,
sibling distance        = 6em,
level distance          = 8em,
edge from parent/.style = {draw, -latex},
every node/.style       = {font=\footnotesize},
sloped
]
\node [root] {$L_2$}
child { node [env] {z}
    edge from parent node [below] {1-p} }
child { node [env] {y}
    edge from parent node [above] {p} };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use comments to suppress the newlines between the pictures:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\let\cleardoublepage=\clearpage
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
treenode/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
    draw, align=center,
    top color=white, bottom color=blue!20},
root/.style     = {treenode, font=\Large, bottom color=red!30},
env/.style      = {treenode, font=\ttfamily\normalsize},
dummy/.style    = {circle,draw}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[
grow                    = right,
sibling distance        = 6em,
level distance          = 8em,
edge from parent/.style = {draw, -latex},
every node/.style       = {font=\footnotesize},
sloped
]
\node [root] {$L_1$}
child { node [env] {z}
    edge from parent node [below] {1-p} }
child { node [env] {x}
    edge from parent node [above] {p} };

\end{tikzpicture}%
%
$\sim$%
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
[
grow                    = right,
sibling distance        = 6em,
level distance          = 8em,
edge from parent/.style = {draw, -latex},
every node/.style       = {font=\footnotesize},
sloped
]
\node [root] {$L_2$}
child { node [env] {z}
    edge from parent node [below] {1-p} }
child { node [env] {y}
    edge from parent node [above] {p} };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This produces
[image: Resulting image]
Note however that the `~` is not in the middle of the pictures. One could possibly use a `\raisebox` or something like that to bring it up there...

---

### Explanation

Every time you put in an empty line, TeX will treat it as the delimiter of the current paragraph which will result in a linebreak. This is why in your example the images were underneath one another.
Comments prevent all following characters in the current line from being seen by TeX. Do do *also* prevent any whitespace (blanks, tabs, newlines) at the *beginning* of the next line and can therefore be used to "left-trim" the content of the following line.
In the given example the placed comments remove any whitespace between the images so that TeX won't produce a linebreak. You could have gotten the same result by removing the whitespace manually (e.g. writing `\end{tikzpicture}\begin{tikzpicture}` without any whitespace in between.